# Android - LinearLayout Background "over" Views

Tags: android, layout, background, view

I am trying to apply a simple gradient background to my main LinearLayout. My problem is that the background refuses to stay in the background and instead decides to also cover my views (TextViews and Buttons, in this case). What am I doing wrong/am I missing? Thanks for your help!

main layout:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mainLinearLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_gradient"
android:orientation="vertical" 
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Select the PC to communicate with..." />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewStatus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Status" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroupDevices"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

</RadioGroup>  

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="&lt;&lt;" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnVolDown"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPlayPause"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="|>" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnVolUp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=">>" />

   </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

drawable/bg_gradient.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#181818" android:startColor="#616161"/>

    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#343434" />
</shape>
```

Result (Screenshot from Eclipse xml editor, but looks the same on the actual phone)
http://s14.directupload.net/images/130415/q8q6hcmn.png

As you can see, the text lines and the buttons appear to be at least partially covered by the background. I also tried to use a normal black background, but with the same result. All views appear "foggy" behind a black haze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are developing for the android version 3 or higher...so in this versions and the versions above the theme is set such as the controls seems to be having transparent background...

try changing the controls(buttons,textviews) background to some hash color values

eg:-`android:background="#ffaaff"`

now you need not to change your code...give it a try as it is...

for your buttons put this in your code to make them transparent...

```
v.setBackgroundColor(0x0000FF00 );
```

hope this works for you

Comment: I am developing for API level 15, indeed. Sorry for leaving that out. Your suggestion does set the background of my text to a nice pink color. I imagined that I could just put the text on my canvas, above the background. But it seems like every text comes with a background, that has to be specified. So I will try to match the Views' backgrounds and the layouts background as good as possible to have a seamless integration of the text. I hope thats the right way to go then. Thank you for your help!

Comment: But it seems like every text comes with a background...can you show me how by sharing some image here...and if you find this useful upvote or accept this as answer

Comment: With your help I was able to set the background of the text to black and the button to white. http://s14.directupload.net/images/130416/4c63r3bc.png
So now the views are not polluted anymore, but its still not the effect I was looking for. I just want (especially the text) to have no visible background and just appear white on the shaded layout background.
I wanted to upvote your answer, but since I am new here I cannot (higher reputation required). I did accept your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Great! Manually setting the background of the text and the buttons to transparent does the trick! http://s7.directupload.net/images/130416/rs3n4uum.png
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I do not see your buttons to be polluted by your gradient. As for the top most text - it's normal as by default TextView background is transparent, so container's bg will be seen thru it.